# Retrieve values from mySQL JSON field

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

Given the following JSON structure stored in one of  the MySQL database fields:

```
{
"ZZZ": {
    "shipp_price_euro": {
        "old": "1",
        "new": "2"
    }
}
```

}

I would like to get the following tabular output:

[image]

I already tried something like this:

```
SELECT json_extract(logs, "$.shipp_price_euro.old"), json_extract(logs, "$.shipp_price_euro.new") FROM some_table
```

However this returns NULLS. I think it's because I'm missing a ref to the parent element in my JSON_EXTRACT() path expression.

Do you know how this could be handled?

**EDIT 20220526_1:**

Please find the schema of the input table:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (logs LONGTEXT);
```

And sample data:

```
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES
(
'{"XXX": {"shipp_price_euro": {"old": "3", "new": "4"}}, 
  "YYY": {"shipp_price_euro": {"old": "5", "new": "6"}}}'
);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you decide to store the data in this JSON format?

Comment: @BillKarwin I'm just designing ETL pipeline to transfer data from the described source into DWH. It was purely app developers decision to store it like this.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I sympathize, I have had to deal with data formats created by naive developers many times.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT some_table.id, 
       jsontable1.json_id,
       jsontable2.old,
       jsontable2.new
FROM some_table
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(logs),
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (json_id VARCHAR(255) PATH '$')) jsontable1
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(JSON_EXTRACT(logs, CONCAT('$.', jsontable1.json_id)),
                      '$.shipp_price_euro' COLUMNS (old INT PATH '$.old',
                                                    new INT PATH '$.new')) jsontable2
```

MySQL 8.0.20 needed.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=017486f62a01cbe9b5b68c4604af4e1e

Comment: for some reason I'm getting the following error: 

"SQL Error [3143] [42000]: (conn=412560403) Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 7."

It specifically refers to the second CROSS JOIN, like it could not accept the CONCAT() expression used for calculating the PATH :/ I'm running the following version of db engine: 8.0.23-14

Comment: @kamilzet_ Please edit the fiddle, add actual table structure, add some data (5-10 rows), reproduce the problem and provide the link.